# Access a class WITHIN a namespace Unity C# pathfinding

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I'm making a game in Unity where 'enemies' spawn in (controlled from a script on a player), I'm using prefabs of the enemies, I have got the enemies to spawn in but the pathfinding isn't working. I know why - it's that when you reference the player transform while the enemy is in the scene there's a link but once the enemy is a prefab it can't access the player's components as it's not in the scene. I did a bit of researching and found the answer - I needed to instantiate the enemies like normal, but set this to a variable, `enemyGO` for example, and then access the enemy's `AIDestinationSetter` script through `enemyGO.GetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>().target = gameObject` - this would assign the `target` value of the pathfinding target to the player (`gameObject`). This would all work well, but it kept saying that it could no find the AIDestinationSetter component. This, after a while of tinkering, proved to be (I think) because in the script, the `AIDestinationSetter` is within a namespace.

Here's the `AIDestinationSetter` code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Pathfinding {
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the destination of an AI to the position of a specified object.
    /// This component should be attached to a GameObject together with a movement script such as AIPath, RichAI or AILerp.
    /// This component will then make the AI move towards the <see cref="target"/> set on this component.
    ///
    /// See: <see cref="Pathfinding.IAstarAI.destination"/>
    ///
    /// [Open online documentation to see images]
    /// </summary>
    [UniqueComponent(tag = "ai.destination")]
    [HelpURL("http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/class_pathfinding_1_1_a_i_destination_setter.php")]
    public class AIDestinationSetter : VersionedMonoBehaviour {
        /// <summary>The object that the AI should move to</summary>
        public Transform target; // THIS IS THE VARIABLE I'M TRYING TO ACCESS
        IAstarAI ai;

        void OnEnable () {
            ai = GetComponent<IAstarAI>();
            // Update the destination right before searching for a path as well.
            // This is enough in theory, but this script will also update the destination every
            // frame as the destination is used for debugging and may be used for other things by other
            // scripts as well. So it makes sense that it is up to date every frame.
            if (ai != null) ai.onSearchPath += Update;
        }

        void OnDisable () {
            if (ai != null) ai.onSearchPath -= Update;
        }

        /// <summary>Updates the AI's destination every frame</summary>
        void Update () {
            if (target != null && ai != null) ai.destination = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's where I'm attempting to access the script from:

```
public GameObject enemyGO; // creating the empty variable

// and then further on in the script:

Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius;
enemyGO = Instantiate(gameObject, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
enemyGO.GetComponent<Pathfinding>().target = spawnPos;
```

Please help if possible, I've been trying to solve this for hours! Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the details of the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably rather ment

```
GetComponent<Pathfinding.AIDestinationSetter>
```

Or have

```
using Pathfinding;
```

on top of your script and simply use

```
GetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>
```

you are currently trying to give a namespace to `GetComponent` which obviously won't work

Comment: Thank you!! this has solved the problem, I'm very grateful!!!